# Model Deforms When Trying to Animate

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I am trying to animate a voxel (cubic) model I made in *MagicaVoxel* using Blender, but when I try to move the feet, the soles of the feet badly deform. Also, when I move the hands, it slightly deforms the shoulder a little bit. This is my first time using blender, so I figured I would need some help for this fix. I want to be able to move the feet, hands, and head without having them deform.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Tweaked three things and got it to work.

[image]

### Tris to Quads

The first thing I did was <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to convert *Tris to Quads*. This is a form of retopologizing that is highly recommended. Triangles are not recommended when modeling.

### Remove Doubles

I keyed <kbd>W</kbd> to open the *Specials* menu and selected *Remove Doubles*. This got rid of excess duplicate vertices that were messing with your *Weight Painting*. Of course, this destroyed the shading, so I added an *Edge Split* modifier in the *Properties panel > Object modifiers tab*.

[image]

### Parenting

After all the changes to the mesh, I redid the parenting. I selected the mesh, then selected the armature, keyed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and chose *Armature Deform > With Automatic Weights*.

[image]

Here is the fixed .blend file:

[image]